# How can I avoid for an undeclared variable breaking Intellisense?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, dojo, intellisense

Yeah, I can already see the upcoming comment trail along the lines of "use declared variables then". But please bear with me.

The situation is that I have a moderate pile of JS files, each containing a Dojo widget. Widgets contain calls to various functions in `dojo` namespace but because `dojo` does not exist in the scope of a widget file, Intellisense breaks.

Here `CTRL`+`[space]` autocomplete includes `this.a` and `this.b` as expected:

```
new Object({
    a: NaN,
    b: function YesToIntellisense()
    {
        console.log(this.a); // CTRL+[space] includes this.a and this.b
    }
});
```

Here `CTRL`+`[space]` autocomplete lacks both `this.a` and `this.b`:

```
new Object({
    a: dojo.foo(),
    b: function NonIntellisense()
    {
        console.log(this.a); // CTRL+[space] does *not* include this.a and this.b
    }
});
```

**How can I avoid for an undeclared variable breaking Intellisense in VS2010?**

Comment: @BenniKa - Did you try that one out before suggesting?

Comment: I don't have visual-studio. => It was silly (from me) to write a comment without knowing it.

Comment: @BenniKa - promise you'll do some research next time and we'll let you off the hook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `/// <reference path="path-to/dojo-file.js" />` tag at the top of this javascript file.  See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2007/11/06/jscript-intellisense-a-reference-for-the-reference-tag.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385682.aspx

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure about VS2010. I use Aptana Studio 3 and this is how i fixed it:

1. There is (in Aptana) a setting called "Project Natures". Here i usually check `Web`, `JavaScript` and `PHP`. See if VS2010 has such a setting.
2. To avoid JavaScript warnings like "use of undeclared variables", i simply set the first line of my js file like this:

   `/*global var1: false, var2: false, var3:false....*/`

See if you can find the equivalent in VS2010.

Sorry if the answer doesnt help. I would have commented only, but i don't have enough rep.
Good luck!

Comment: Probably best not to provide an answer for VS 2010 if you don't use it.